# variable won't update on component

Tags: reactjs

I'm taking a foreign language and translating it. This is my first react project and the problem is that `finalText` isn't updated with the translation.

I can do a `console.log(translation)` inside the googleTranslate function and it works. When I try to assign it to the finalText variable above the scope of that function it will not display, it's always blank.

```
import React from 'react';

class CardComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let data = this.props.data;


        let truncated = data.truncated;
        var test = new String(truncated);
        console.log(test);
        var finalText = '';

        var googleTranslate = require('google-translate')('apikey');
        googleTranslate.translate(data.text, 'en', function(err, translation) {
            finalText = translation;
          });

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-3 hoverable thin">
                    <div className="row valign-wrapper">
                        <div className="col s2">
                            <img src={data.user.profile_image_url} alt={data.user.name} className="circle responsive-img" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s10 left-align">
                        {(() => {
                        if (test=='true') {
                        return (
                            <span className="black-text"> {data.extended_tweet.full_text}</span>
                        )
                        } else {
                        return (
                            <span className="black-text">translated text: {finalText}</span>
                        )
                        }
                    })()}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div className="row valign-wrapper right-align chip hoverable">
                    {new Date(data.created_at).toLocaleTimeString()}
                    </div>
                    <div className="row valign-wrapper right-align chip hoverable">
                        <a href={`https://twitter.com/${data.user.screen_name}`} target="_blank">{`@${data.user.screen_name}`}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CardComponent;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that the translation occurs asynchronously. You make the call to Google, and then instead of waiting, the rest of your code runs until Google responds. However, by the time Google responds, it's too late and you've already rendered everything. The reason that the console log works is because it's asynchronous too! It's slower than Google, so it happens after you get the result back.

Luckily, with React, there is an easy fix. We can start your code when the component mounts, and then when Google responds, we can tell React to do the render again. Learn more about this here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

```js
class CardComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.state = {finalText: ''};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let data = this.props.data;
        let truncated = data.truncated;

        var googleTranslate = require('google-translate')('apikey');
        googleTranslate.translate(data.text, 'en', function(err, translation) {
            // by calling set state, React will know to render again
            this.setState({
                finalText: translation
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // all the html you want to render in here
            <p>this.state.finalText</p>
        );
    }
}
```